# Using IntelliJ IDEA and the Dart plugin, where does the Dart exceptions end up?

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, angular2-dart

I've been playing with Angular2 using IntelliJ IDEA (2016.3.5) and the latest Dart plugin, and I just can't figure out where the errors, exceptions, assert failures etc. ends up.

I am running Dartium with `DART_FLAGS="--checked"` and `pub serve` seems to default to debug mode as far as I can read. Dart2js is configured to run in checked mode as well and the analysis server is configured for strong mode. I have also tried using the JetBrains Chrome extension so I get everything shown directly in IDEA, including the console saying `Observatory listening at http://127.0.0.1:35517/`.

When there are no errors the Angular2 Dart app runs just fine in Dartium but if I add an assert some where in the code, ie. on a button trigger, the app just stops working at that point with no error output anywhere. Same goes if there's some other error somewhere that `pub serve` didn't detect.

Dart and Dartium are both at the currently latest version, 1.22.1.

Comment: Sounds like https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2/issues/277#issuecomment-279690371

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, that was exactly it. Sooo many hours wasted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be fixed in Angular3 beta.x due to be released the next days it seems.